# How can I find my desired table inside a set of nested tables, using bs4/python, if there are no class or id attributes?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have the following intricated HTML structure from which I have to parse through nested tables and scrape from my desired table. There are many tables in the page. I am quiet cannot figure out how to reach that table which has the data to be scraped. Here is the URL of the page.

http://www.teauction.com/industry/buyer/coimbuyera-z.asp

Comment: Is this a general question - like you have many pages and want a solution that will work across them? Or are you looking for a solution for this particular page? It seems like you are in-between asking an HTML parsing question, and a DOM traversal question, or not sure which one to ask?

Comment: Right now it is not a general question as I find only this website having such difficulty.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code you are using, that normally works but does not work here. That would give a better context for providing an answer. However, for a case specific work-around, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BeautifulSoup, we could do something like:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def filter_function(tag):
    return ((tag.name=='h3' and tag.parent.name=='td' and '2' in
             [tag.parent[attrib] for attrib in tag.parent.attrs.keys()]) or
            (tag.name == 'p' and tag.parent.name=='td' and '2' in
             [tag.parent[attrib] for attrib in tag.parent.attrs.keys()]))

our_url = 'http://www.teauction.com/industry/buyer/coimbuyera-z.asp'

our_page = urllib2.urlopen(our_url).read()

our_soup = BeautifulSoup(our_page)

nodes_we_want = our_soup.find_all(filter_function)

text_we_want = [node.text for node in nodes_we_want]
```

You could actually combine the whole thing into a really ugly one liner with a lambda for the helper function, but this is a bit easier to follow.

The real trick here is in defining the parameters for `our_soup.find_all`. This required analyzing the page and realizing what our target nodes have in common - they are all children of a `td` node that has a `colspan` attribute of value `2`. This set of shared properties is not true of any other elements of in the page, so they are good filter criteria.

There are other ways to accomplish the same goal, probably some that are better, but I like this one because our output will retain the same order as it appears on the page. I would be careful, however, since the text contains non ASCII characters, to be sure to handle the text properly once extracted.

**EDIT:**

Based on an updated description of desire output, these would do the trick:

`text_we_want` as a list of tuples containing name, details pairs --

```
text_we_want = [(nodes_we_want[h].text.strip('\r\n'),
                 nodes_we_want[h+1].text.replace('\r\n              ',''))
                 for h in range(0,len(nodes_we_want)-1,2)]
```

`text_we_want` as a list of strings, each of which contains the name and details for one company (I've inserted a tab between name and details, but this is easily removed) --

```
text_we_want = ['\t'.join((nodes_we_want[h].text.strip('\r\n'),
                 nodes_we_want[h+1].text.replace('\r\n              ','')))
                 for h in range(0,len(nodes_we_want)-1,2)]
```

Comment: Of course, it would be helpful if we passed the page into the soup. :) Updated to correct this oversight.

Comment: I started off by traversing through sibling method in BS4. But that dint work. BTW I am using your answer and it quiet seems to work.

Comment: The structure of the page you are working on is pretty terrible. I would never have reached a purely programmatic solution for this case - though there may be one. My solution is hacked together by directly viewing the page source for your target page, and finding the simplest pattern that correctly describes only the desired output - passing filter functions (which can also be regex functions) to `find_all` is a nice option in bs4.

Comment: I have modified the last two lines of your code `for nodes_we_want in  our_soup.find_all(filter_function):
    text_we_want = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', node).strip().encode('utf8') for node in nodes_we_want.find_all(text=True) if node.strip()]
    print text_we_want
`

Comment: @Venky - the edits were rejected, it seems, but it looks like you're prettifying the output a bit. That's fine - you made no mention of desired output / formatting. It's worth noting, you will also have stuff like the section headers and the giant capital letters that go with them in the output of my answer, which could be removed in various ways. But your question said you wanted the text of this particular table, so that is what my answer gives.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41548/discussion-between-venky-and-selllikesybok)

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar before and found the [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library really useful. You could write something like:

```
def getThis(theThingYouWantToSearch, yourHTMLstring):
    searchResults = re.findall('<table.*?</table>(?ims)',yourHTMLstring)
```

This will basically search everything that has this structure:

```
"<table (whatever) </table>".
```

Then you can just loop through it and find the table that you want.

**EDIT:**

Actually solving your problem, I came up with this:

```
import re
import urllib

def getThis(theThingYouWantToSearch, yourHTMLstring):

    searchResults = re.findall('<h3.*?/p>(?ims)',yourHTMLstring)

    for match in searchResults:
        if theThingYouWantToSearch in match:
            return match

URL = 'http://www.teauction.com/industry/buyer/coimbuyera-z.asp'
htmlstring = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()

print getThis('A.M.S', htmlstring)
```

The first re.findall() finds all the strings that have this shape:

```
<h3 (something) /p>
```

And then I loop through the matches to get the one with 'A.M.S.'

**To get everything:**

```
def getAll(yourHTMLstring):

    searchResults = re.findall('<h3.*?/p>(?ims)',yourHTMLstring)
    return searchResults
```

Comment: This  gives the table on the left side. I was trying to get the personal details which is on the right `td`

Comment: @Venky well then replace all the 'table' in the code with 'td' and see how it works (and say how it goes)

Comment: @Venky This is confusing, while looking at your HTML I saw that the personal details of the right are not written as a table but as individual paragraphs. So your question is quite misleading...

Comment: @Venky I know you are not going to use this, but you just needed to change <table with <h3 and /table> with /p>. Then it works as you want. But please make it clearer next time

Comment: I am sorry if I was wrong. but I hope it is not. every detail comes under one table which I could reach.

Comment: No. I tried your answer first. I changed it to `td`. It still gave me the left table.

Comment: @Venky Now look at the change: searchResults contains all the singular buyers. I just looked for one of them, A.M.S. But you have all the buyers in the list searchResult. so the code could be reduced to only the re.findall() function

Comment: @JGallo They are individual `<p>` and `<h3>` elements, which are children of a `<td>`, which is a child of a `<table>`, which is a child of... well, heck, just look at the xpath of the first company name! `/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/h3[1]`

Comment: @selllikesybok Yes, it's quite messy... but I guessed that Venky wanted the information of every singular buyer, and that's why I use <h3 ... /p>. I guessed you did more or less the same in your answer

Comment: @JGallo That is getting that particular person detail all good. But for everything I dont find any common keyword.

Comment: @Venky You have everything in searchResults! Just store it in another variable or do with it whatever you want. searchResults is a list with the information of every buyer. so seearchResults[0] is a buyer, sR[1] another and so on. If you want everything just print all the items of searchREsults.

Comment: @JGallo Yes, since the '<p>' are not children of their corresponding '<h3>', it is better to capture them simultaneously, otherwise you have to reconstruct the list in correct order later. My answer is based on bs4 because the question is tagged this way, and because regex for html parsing? srsly? ;) Of course, Venky has not specified how he wants the output to appear - if he wants it more structured (like a dict of name:detail pairs, or just a list of name, details tuples), the approach would change a little.

Comment: @selllikesybok Oh! I realised now that the question was not WITHOUT bs4 but without class or id // bs4 python. Did'nt get he was asking for a bs4 solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use htql from http://htql.net to parse out the content.  Here is the sample code:

```
import urllib
URL = 'http://www.teauction.com/industry/buyer/coimbuyera-z.asp'
htmlstring = urllib.urlopen(URL).read()

import htql
d=htql.query(htmlstring, """
   <table>3.<Table>3.<tr>1.<td>1.<hr sep> {
      title=<h3>.<b> &tx; 
      address=<p>0 :tx; 
      category=<big> &tx; 
      |title is not null 
   }
   """); 

d[:1]
# [('A.M.S. TEA TRADERS', '<font face="Arial" size="2">38, Ramachandra Road <br>\r\n              R.S.Puram <br>\r\n              Coimbatore - 641002<br>\r\n              Phone -(+91 422) 470441</font>', 'Coimbatore \r\n            Buyers A ')]
```